# JQuery Slide Show Simplification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to come up with the most basic example of making a JQuery slide show where you click on the current image you're viewing and you cycle through a gallery of photos. I know its probably not the most basic example, because if I want to add a new image I have to code more JQuery. Is there a more abstract approach where I don't have to code JQuery in terms of div id's and let classes take care of the work? Here is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#pic1").click(function() {
$("#pic1").hide();
$("#pic2").show();                
});  
$("#pic2").click(function() {
$("#pic2").hide();
$("#pic3").show();                
});
$("#pic3").click(function() {
$("#pic3").hide();
$("#pic1").show();                
});
});
```

The rest is here. http://jsfiddle.net/XjdTX/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will as simple as you want,

```
$("#slideframe div").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
        $(this).next().show();
    } else {
        $("#slideframe div").first().show();
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XjdTX/5/

Comment: excellent. I'm going to have to take some time and think about this code as I am relatively new to simlifying JQuery but thank you!

Comment: welcome. and hope you will accept the answer once you realize the it